# how the extern variable define and initialize?

Tags: c, embedded-linux

In my code, one line of externally variables is written. I am not able to decode it. Below:

```c
KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN U8_T KBS_Tick KEYBOARD_H_INIT ( 0 );
```

What I found:

1. `KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN` is `#define KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN extern`.
2. `U8_T` is `typedef unsigned short int U8_T`.
3. `KBS_tick` is variable what is assumed but not able to decode, is initialized with 0 or something else.
4. `KEYBOARD_H_INIT` is defined thus: `#define KEYBOARD_H_INIT(VALUE)`.

Comment: Can you find out how `KEYBOARD_H_INIT` is defined?

Comment: Just replace all the macros and typedef with their expansions.

Comment: #define KEYBOARD_H_INIT(VALUE) in keyboard.h header file

Comment: extern variables are (as the name suggests) defined/initialized somewhere else (in another module). That is just a declaration that let you use correctly the variable in that module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your preprocessor defines, what you have is then a simple external declaration:

```c
extern unsigned short int KBS_Tick;
```

Keep in mind you can usually use a compiler flag to stop after the preprocessing stage (such as with `gcc -E`) and see what it translates to.

---

The most *likely* reason it's done this way is so you can use the exact same line for declaring the external (for *users* of a module) and defining the variable (for the module *itself*). The line:

```c
KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN U8_T KBS_Tick KEYBOARD_H_INIT ( 0 );
```

can generate both variations:

```c
typedef unsigned short int U8_T;

#define KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN extern
#define KEYBOARD_H_INIT(VALUE)
KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN U8_T KBS_Tick KEYBOARD_H_INIT ( 0 );
// -> extern unsigned short int KBS_Tick;

#define KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN
#define KEYBOARD_H_INIT(VALUE) = VALUE
KEYBOARD_H_EXTERN U8_T KBS_Tick KEYBOARD_H_INIT ( 0 );
// -> unsigned short int KBS_Tick = 0;
```

Comment: what I found #define KEYBOARD_H_INIT(VALUE) in keyboard.h header file